# The product of two rational Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> If $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $C_a$ and $C_b$ are both positive rational Dedekind cuts then $C_a\cdot
> C_b=C_{a\cdot b}$.

First of all this is my definition of product:

Let $r,s$ Dedekind cuts such that $r,s\geq 0$. Then $r\cdot s:=C_0\cup\{pq\mid (p,q\geq 0)\wedge (p\in r, q\in s)\} $.

I have no problem proving that $ C_a\cdot C_b\subseteq C_{a\cdot b}$, but the other way around. So, let $\alpha \in C_{a\cdot b}$. If $\alpha<0$ or $\alpha=0$ then according to the definition $\alpha\in C_a\cdot C_b$.  If $\alpha>0$ my idea is that since $\alpha <ab$ then $\frac {\alpha}{ab}<1$ and because we need to find $a'<a$ and $b'<b$ such that $a'b'<ab$ we could put $\frac {\alpha}{ab}=mn$ such that $m,n<1$. If this is possible then we can have $\alpha=(a\cdot m)(b\cdot n)=ab(mn)=ab(\frac {\alpha}{ab})$ where  $a'=(a\cdot m)<a$ and also $b'=(b\cdot n)<b$. Therefore $\alpha \in C_a\cdot C_b$.

Comment: This seems to work. To find $m,n$ such that $\alpha/ab=mn$ and $m,n<1$, just choose any $m$ between $\alpha/ab$ and $1$, and then set $n=\alpha/abm$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes it seems to work indeed. I don't know how do you came up with this choice of $m$ but yes, thank you so much. I'll wait for any other comments just in case. Your comment would be the answer actually. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, you're looking for two rational numbers $m,n<1$ whose product is $\alpha/ab$. If they exist at all, they will both be larger than $\alpha/ab$. Luckily, if $m$ is rational then $n$ will automatically be rational, since $\alpha/ab$ is rational. And it turns out that these two necessary conditions on $m$ (being between $\alpha/ab$ and $1$, and being rational) suffice to make the whole solution work.